# Grouping data rows of a file

Tags: c#

I have a tab delimited text file structured like this:

```
Name  ID     Address   Car      Weight  Salary  Married   Kids
Bo    1234   123 Main  Nissan   190    
Bo    1234   123 Main                   85000    
John  456    5th Ave   Jag      176     99000   No        1
Bo    1234                                      Yes       4
```

Notice `Bo` has three rows in this example, his rows could even be scattered among the file, I mean they don't need to be on sequential one after another either.

I want to parse this file for each Person, the way I know it is a unique person is combination of his Name and ID so in this example three rows for Bo that his info is among them, for example first row has his weight, second row has his Salary, etc... so I am looing for a way to gather all rows related to each person in one place so I can have all his info in one place so I can go and populate my Database table based on that. 
What structure and algorithms do you suggest?

Comment: Youre getting ahead of yourself I think.  First, parse the file.  Get it into a structure, say a list of a custom class with properties for each column.  Then using linq it should not be hard to coalesce  your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1).Select(c =>
                                                 {
                                                     var split = c.Split('\t');

                                                     return new {
                                                         Name = split[0],
                                                         ID = split[1],
                                                         Address = split[2],
                                                         Car = split[3],
                                                         Weight = split[4],
                                                         Salary = split[5],
                                                         Married = split[6],
                                                         Kids = split[7],
                                                     };
                                                 }).GroupBy(c => c.Name);
```

Then you'll have to write some logic to merge together the rows that come from each `IGrouping<>` here, but this should be the gist of it. You'll also, of course, want to parse `int`s and other types, but again, this should be the gist of it.